# Open Source projects with encryption keys

Tags: software, source-code, api, security, cryptography

I currently have a project which I'm planning in the not too distant future to open source on GitHub.

The question I have is regarding how open source projects are released if they have encryption keys.

Basically, the project consists of an Android app (not being open sourced) and a PHP API.

The PHP API can potentially send/receive confidential information such as authentication details. Obviously, the API should be run under HTTPS to offer some security, but on top of that, the Android app, will encrypt all the data, then once encrypted and it sends the request to the PHP API. The PHP API decrypts the request and then generates a response, which is then encrypted and the response is sent back to the Android app to decrypt and process.

The encryption between the Android app and the PHP API has a hard coded encryption key (I'm using 256 AES encryption). It doesn't seem right that this key is kept in the open source code as then if someone managed to find a way to do a man in the middle attack between the app and the API, they have the key, potentially exposing the user authentication details.

What's the recommended way for doing this? Should I just not offer encryption, and just rely on the user using HTTPS, and if they don't, it's their problem or is there an alternative method I could use?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with this, so I'm writing as a comment instead of an answer. You could encrypt the private key of your project with the public key of some continuous integration server. Your continuous integration server could then decrypt your project's private key when building it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not include keys in your open source project. You should include a *file location* where your code *expects* a key, and the user (or an included utility) creates or copies their own unique key into the expected location. Imagine a thousand people download your project and stand up their own versions of your open-source server -- what's the point of having encryption if all of those servers are simply using the same key?

Including one specific encryption key is like drawing up a blueprint of a house that includes the specific tooth-sizes of the lock and key to the front door. It's completely the wrong approach: whenever a builder constructs a house from your blueprints, the builder should grab a totally new, unique lock and key and put that in the front door. It's not necessary that your blueprints specify an exact lock in your blueprints. It's merely important that the house *has* a lock; each separate construction project will supply its own lock.

Your own deployment of your open source server will have its own unique key, just like all other deployments that you don't control will have their own unique keys. The public, open-source project itself should have *no* key, because the entire point of a secret key is to keep it local to a particular deployment.

---

That said, using encryption within HTTPS seems unnecessary. HTTPS is sufficient to keep the user's traffic private and unaltered -- that's the exact scope what HTTPS was designed to do. As for "if they don't [use HTTPS] its their problem," simply *don't offer an unencrypted HTTP service* on your server.

Are you hoping to implement this as a kind of DRM to keep the traffic secret from the original user? If so, this will work about as well as any DRM, which is to say: it will work well enough for users who don't care about it, and not well enough to keep out tech-savvy users.

Comment: That's a great answer. I don't offer HTTP for the web service it is only HTTPS, but I'm providing the option for the user to be able to install the API on their own server and tell the app to point to that instead as the API is connecting to their MySQL database (which is the purpose of the API). So I guess the best option would be, if I stick to doing the encryption as a backup, a config file within the API can determine what the key is, and in the app, if they choose to use their own server, it then asks them for key and that key is always used, and they put that in to the config for the API

Comment: +1, but I'd like to add that many people will use environment variables for this purpose as well. (Or the windows registry.)